# How to replace end of line character with a new line in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I want to replace

```
Insert into table values('A','B');
Insert into table values('C','D');
```

with

```
Insert into table values('A','B');
commit;
Insert into table values('C','D');
commit;
```

In short replace

```
);
```

with

```
);
commit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Without regex, you can replace

```
);
```

with

```
);
commit;
```

By changing the *search mode* to `Extended (\n, \r, \t, \0, \x...)` you can include new lines in your replacement string, represented by the `\n` escape sequence.

*Find what :* `);`

*Replace with :* `);\ncommit;`

<kbd>Replace All</kbd>

[Replace dialog - Search Mode: Extended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Egr6.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to specifically target `INSERT` statements, then we can try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    ^(Insert into \w+ values\([^)]+\);)
Replace: $1\ncommit;
```

Here is a working demo:

### Demo

Edit:

A more general pattern you may use to capture your `INSERT` statements might be this:

```
^(Insert into .*?;)
```

Be certain to use the `matches newline` option in the regex dialog box, so that `.*` can match across multiple lines, should that be necessary.  Then, use the same replacement as above.

Comment: Actually i have huge insert commands.. to wrap everything via reg exp would be difficult...Any other help?

Comment: Then you didn't ask a very representative question.  Edit your question and show us the actual problem.

Comment: what i exactly want is to replace 
); with
);
commit;

Comment: @sssophkc Then probably directly adapting Tim's answer will do: Find `);$` (where `$` means end-of-line) and Replace: `$1\ncommit;`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try with this:

Search Mode: `Regular Expression`

Search what: `\R*$`

Replace by: `\r\ncommit;`  (or use any other line ending you prefer)

<kbd>Replace All</kbd>

**NOTE**: If you have mixed sql statements and you just want to add commits after inserts, then you'll need to user other approach